# Hide windows powershell when an application run

Tags: python, windows, pygame, console-application

I have coded an application in python using the pygame library. Everything work, but when I run the application, it also opens the shell. Is there a way to hide the shell?

[image: this is an screenshot for clarity]

I have tried to mute the pygame 'welcome message', thinking that was it that opened the shell when I run the application(don't pay attention to the 'here' string printed on the shell, it is for debugging stuff and the shell is opened also without it), but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the application using `pythonw` instead of `python`.  `pythonw` is the exact same Python interpreter, but it's marked as a Windows GUI application, so it doesn't require a connection to a console.